# ChromeCast Video with iOS App using local url (Error)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, chromecast, google-cast

I am trying Chromecast to play my local url video. I am not familiar how to implement, the below is code which tried,
I could'nt find much libraries to do Chromecast with local url and play video by controlling phone as remote(play/stop). If any one know could guide with good libraries or suggest code for it. Please..

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let castButton = GCKUICastButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
    castButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
    let castBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: castButton)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = castBarButtonItem
    Casty.shared.initialize()
    let url: String  = "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/mp4/DesigningForGoogleCast.mp4"
    let subtitleURL = "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/tracks/DesigningForGoogleCast-en.vtt"
    let subtitle = GCKMediaTrack(identifier: 1, contentIdentifier: subtitleURL , contentType: "text/vtt", type: GCKMediaTrackType.text, textSubtype: GCKMediaTextTrackSubtype.captions, name: "English", languageCode: "en", customData: nil)

    //this image will show up in expanded controller as well as video thumb
    let image = GCKImage(url: URL(string: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/images/780x1200/DesigningForGoogleCast-887x1200.jpg")!, width: 780, height: 1200)

    Casty.didStartSession = { _ in
        Casty.shared.loadMedia(url: self.url , subtitles: [subtitle] , activeSubtitleID: 1 , title: "Dev" , image: image)
        Casty.shared.presentExpandedController()
        Casty.shared.addMiniController(toParentViewController: self)
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cast media player only supports playback over HTTP. Therefore you will need to have a local web server to allow the player to access your local content.